# .htaccess for Zend Framework - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have in my server catalog admin, where I have Zend Framework project.

In my .htaccess (located in admin/public) I have:

```
RewriteEngine on 

php_value short_open_tag 1
RewriteBase /admin/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/admin/public/js/.*\.js)$
RewriteRule /(.*\.js)$ /admin/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|xml|avi|flv|mov|mp3|wav)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But I get error:
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

I checked, whether mod_rewrite works, and it does.
This .htaccess in main  folder works properly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-F
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ test.php?test=$1
```

Could anyone tell me, how my .htaccess for Zend should look like?
I used identical with this project on other servers and it worked.

Oh, and I don't have access to error.log

Comment: Try removing stuff from the htaccess till the error disappears. I don't see anything that would cause an error. Your first rewriterule should not start with a `/` but that doesn't produce a 500 error.

Comment: Thank You very much for the tip! I started removing with "php_value short_open_tag 1" and that was it - now it works. Strange though, because it worked with that on other servers.

Comment: PHP_VALUE won't work if your PHP engine is loaded as CGI/FastCGI and not as Apache module. I think that is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [htscanner](http://pecl.php.net/package/htscanner) PHP module if you want to use `php_value` in your .htaccess files when running php as a CGI/FastCGI application instead of running php as Apache module.

Answer (score 0):

plz try

```
php_value short_open_tag on
```

instead of
`php_value short_open_tag 1`

this may resolve your issue